# Custom JSON serialization for Java datatypes

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, jax-rs, mobilefirst-adapters, jsonserializer

In MobileFirst Foundation 8.0, are there any hook points to add a custom JSON serialization for Java datatypes in Java adapters?

For example: Using a Date object in a pojo class, this gets serialized to a default format "2016-09-27T12:11:17.430Z". I need to serialize this only to show the date value, stripping off time related information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [@JsonFormat JAX-RS annotation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html)? From its description:

> General-purpose annotation used for configuring details of how values of properties are to be serialized. Unlike most other Jackson annotations, annotation does not have specific universal interpretation: instead, effect depends on datatype of property being annotated (or more specifically, deserializer and serializer being used).

Java adapters are essentially [JAX-RS applications](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/java-adapters/) and you can add annotations...